# How can I install a command-line tool globally using npm, so that it remains accessible across different Node.js versions?

Tags: node.js, command-line, node-modules, nvm, nvm-windows

I am using **nvm** (Node Version Manager) to manage multiple versions of **Node.js** on my system and
i would like to install a command-line tool *globally* so that it remains accessible even when I switch to a different **Node.js** version using the `nvm use <version>` command.

I want the tool to be available globally, similar to how [pipx](https://github.com/pypa/pipx) with Python.

I have tried installing the command-line tool *globally* using `npm install -g <tool>`. However, this approach only installs the tool within the **Node.js** folder of the specific version I am currently using with **nvm**. When I switch to a different **Node.js** version, the tool becomes inaccessible.

I Want the globally installed tool to remain accessible across all **Node.js** versions managed by **nvm**, regardless of the version I am currently using, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that with NVM because NVM keeps an isolated environment for each Node version.

You can make a script that installs a package on all versions that you have installed:

```
#!/bin/bash

PACKAGE="your-package"

versions=$(nvm ls --no-colors | grep -o -E 'v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')

for version in $versions
do
  echo "Installing $PACKAGE on Node.js $version..."
  nvm install $version
  npm install -g $PACKAGE
done
```